# How do I loop in this if / else program

Tags: c++

the question asks me to repeat this program until users enter X. what should I do to loop this program? should I use while?
question: *repeat the program until the user enter X for package code*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    
    int price_package;
    char package_code;
    int num;
    int no_of_adults;
    int no_of_childs;
        
    cout<<"Enter package code: ";
    cin>>package_code;
         
    if(package_code=='A'){
        
            cout<<"Enter number of adults: ";
            cin>>no_of_adults;
            cout<<"Enter number of childs: ";
            cin>>no_of_childs;
    
            price_package= ((40*no_of_adults)+(21*no_of_childs));   
            cout<<"price package: RM"<<price_package<<endl;
    }
    else if(package_code=='B'){
        
            cout<<"Enter number of adults: ";
            cin>>no_of_adults;
            cout<<"Enter number of childs: ";
            cin>>no_of_childs;
            price_package=((23*no_of_adults)+(14*no_of_childs));
            cout<<"price package: RM"<<price_package<<endl;
         
    }
    else if(package_code=='C'){
        
            cout<<"Enter number of adults: ";
            cin>>no_of_adults;
            cout<<"Enter number of childs: ";
            cin>>no_of_childs;
    
            price_package=((38*no_of_adults)+(18*no_of_childs));
            cout<<"price package: RM"<<price_package<<endl;
        
    }
    else{
            cout<<"ERROR";
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use whatever you wish to use in order to meet the stated requirements.

Comment: How about a do { // most of your code goes here } while ( package_code != 'X');

Comment: where should i put the package_code!='X' ?

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with loops, e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_do_while_loop.asp

Comment: You should also familiarize yourself with input validation, e.g. `if (!(cin>>no_of_adults)) { /* handle error, clear stream state, ignore to \n */ }` -- otherwise you will become familiar with infinite loops....

Answer (score 3):

You could use a while loop or a do while loop. Both of which would look like the following:

```
// import and variables here
do{
// logic to loop
} while(package_code!='X')
```

Or

```
// imports and variables
//declare package_code with some value other than 'X'
while(package_code!='X'){
//loop logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Output(int no_of_adults, int no_of_childs, int price_package)
{
    cout<<"Enter number of adults: ";
    cin>>no_of_adults;
    cout<<"Enter number of childs: ";
    cin>>no_of_childs;
    cout<<"price package: RM"<<price_package<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    int price_package;
    char package_code;
    int num;
    int no_of_adults;
    int no_of_childs;
        
    while (1)
    {
        cout<<"Enter package code: ";
        cin>>package_code;
        
        if(package_code=='A')
        {
            price_package= ((40*no_of_adults)+(21*no_of_childs));
            Output(no_of_adults, no_of_childs, price_package);
        }
        else if(package_code=='B')
        {
            price_package=((23*no_of_adults)+(14*no_of_childs));
            Output(no_of_adults, no_of_childs, price_package);
        }
        else if(package_code=='X')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"ERROR"<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```